# Illuminate \ Http \ Exceptions \ PostTooLargeException in laravel

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I'm try to upload 26Mb file. But I'm getting Illuminate \ Http \ Exceptions \ PostTooLargeException. I changed php.ini file and restart nginx, fpm

In my server after running this command I'm getting 250M

```
php -i | grep "post_max"
post_max_size => 250M => 250M
```

But my php.ini shows post_max_size 8M

I restrt nginx and fpm but nothing works

I'm still getting this error

```
Illuminate \ Http \ Exceptions \ PostTooLargeException
```

Comment: have u configured php.ini file (post_max_size=10240M)

Comment: no I configured it (post_max_size=250M) 
Should I increase? Doesn't matter what I give laravel is still getting 8M for some reason

Comment: No.. thats fine. what php version are you using?

Comment: I'm using php 7.4 ubuntu and nginx

Comment: make sure your nginx allow that much upload size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check your php version

```
php --version 


PHP 7.2.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jun 22 2018 08:44:50) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
if your php version is 7.2
```

open this file `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini`

Update these 2 fields to something that big enough. `Ex. 1024M or 2048M`

```
post_max_size = 1024M                                                                                                            
upload_max_filesize = 1024M  
Restart the php

service php7.2-fpm restart
```

Comment: Thanks it worked I had changed on cli php.ini that's why it was not working after changing in fpm php.ini as you mentioned it works

Answer (score 0):

as you have setup in php upload size you should also update in nginx config

```sh
client_max_body_size 250M;
```

then restart nginx `sudo servicve restart nginx`